# An internal error occurred during: "Resolver". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, oomph

when every time i open  eclipse , it will pop out a series of bugs as follows
thanks for anyone who can help me handle the bugs

work environment:ubuntu 16.04 ，eclipse version：eclipse-jee-oxygen-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

```
    An internal error occurred during: "Load https://github.com/meysholdt/Xpect/raw/master/org.xpect.releng/Xpect.setup".
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    An internal error occurred during: "Load https://github.com/meysholdt/Xpect/raw/master/org.xpect.releng/Xpect.setup".
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    An internal error occurred during: "Load https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanKoehnlein/FXDiagram/master/de.fxdiagram.docs/FXDiagram.setup".
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    An internal error occurred during: "Load https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanKoehnlein/FXDiagram/master/de.fxdiagram.docs/FXDiagram.setup".
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    An internal error occurred during: "Load https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LorenzoBettini/javamm/master/javamm.workspace/Javamm.setup".
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    An internal error occurred during: "Load https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LorenzoBettini/javamm/master/javamm.workspace/Javamm.setup".
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    An internal error occurred during: "Load https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LorenzoBettini/xsemantics/master/devtools/it.xsemantics.workspace/Xsemantics.setup".
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    An internal error occurred during: "Resolver".
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    Resolver 
    Resolver
```

Comment: Seems to be an issue of some [Oomph setup tasks](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring). Do you still get this error if you check **_Skip automatic task execution at startup time_** in _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks_?

Comment: I am having the same issue. It does not happen everytime I start the application, but regularly.
The problem i see in the (proxy) log file is: eclipse tries to connect to URL http://www.eclipse.org/setups/setups.zip as well as to the URLs that are stored within the zip file. At first it does NOT provide any Proxy credentials so our proxy rejects the connection. Afterwards it uses the proxy and is able to fetch the data.

Note: I have set the flag to skip automatic task execution, but it still tries to download the zip.
The proxy settings are set to 'native' (and do work usually)

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall eclipse
I had a similar problem, fixed it just by deleting Eclipse and its workspace and reinstalling it and creating a new workspace.
though you may not have to delete your workspace